# What is the correct way to reflect environment changes to previous versions of software?

Tags: git, version-control, bitbucket

What is the correct way to reflect latest environment changes to previous branches/tags considering you may wish to checkout those tags and should be able to run the code successfully.

My application depends on another application for data, let's call it source app. Source app is very stable and undergoes changes very rarely.
Recently they changed the way we could access their data and the change is very small like 2-3 lines.

Now I was thinking if I checkout the previous version and try to run it; it wont be able to access the data.
So if I want to propagate these changes to all previous branches/tags do I have to re-checkout and re-tag all branches so they work properly?

How much previous versions should Ideally I care to update?  Am I overthinking about making all versions work, considering we mostly work with latest versions? 
What I am trying to understand is what is the preferred strategy to propagate such kind of changes to older software versions which are not bugs/fixes but rather environment changes.

I am using git with bitbucket for source control.

Comment: Is the older version of your application *expected* and/or *required* to run against the newer version of theirs?

Comment: There is no such expectation. Also there is no precedent as application is new. Personally I think at-least one version older code shall be patched in case we want to fallback.

Comment: @darkKnight How do you manage the source app in your own git repo, just commit the source app as common files in your git repo? And does the source app manage in another repo or not, if the source app manage in a different git repo, you can treat the source app repo as submodule or subtree for your own repo, so that you won't need to update the source app manage for pervious versions.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT The source app is not our app and is not maintained in our git repo. More accurately the source app is a HIVE database schema and won't change. But the way we connect to it may change with HIVE version but is very rare.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen sorry wasn't well acquainted with posting so did not tag you in earlier comment . With your comment I think I really got my answer; it will really depend on which versions may be _required_ to run. In our case it will be one version older if it comes to it. So makes sense to patch only it. Thanks!

Comment: @darkKnight Since your problem has been solved, you can add an answer for how you solved it, then mark your own answer. And it will also benefit others who have similar questions :)